# Knocking everything over

Tags: cats, behavior, training

We have a male cat who is about 1.7 years old. Neutered 5 months ago. Just recently, he has started climbing on cabinets and knocking everything off that he can. He has now reverted to knocking anything and everything off of any surface he can find. Help!

Comment: what have you done to adapt the area for your cat,cat tree-shelves-toys-scratching posts,things to keep the cat acctive that satisfies it`s need to climb and gives the cat an elevated area where it can rest and are able to watch the area from a safe place.

Comment: In addition to trond hansen's comments, what other enrichment does your cat have? Toys, engagement with people in the household, etc? Cats are notorious for knocking things off flat surfaces and it's unlikely you'll completely stop it, but knowing what else the cat has available to do can help lead to an answer on how to reduce the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

probably, every time he knocks something over, you are giggling, telling him off, shouting, saying he shouldn't do this?

he is loving the attention from you and finding it a wonderful game!

solution: put only invaluable things on the surfaces and ignore him completely when he knocks these things off.  Give it a week or two and he will have become pretty bored by doing it:)

and let him go out!

Comment: Do you mean 'invaluable'? Why would you put your most expensive things out to have them knocked off?

Answer (score 1):

Your cat is bored, and so it is figuring out fun games to play. If you don't like it, make the thing it's doing less fun, and figure out some other more fun activity for it to do instead. I suggest putting away as many items as you can from your tables and counters, so it has a minimum to knock off. For more appropriate activities, try playing with your cat, or giving it new toys. Experiment and figure out what engages it. If nothing else, try getting it a cat tree and placing it in the area where the cat is climbing on counters, and place toys and such on it that it's allowed to knock off.